# Is there a multi Sig Explorer or Stats provider?

Tags: blockchain, multi-signature, blockchain-explorer

Is there a resource where I can get the past and current number of multi sig transactions, all types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for 'bare multisig' transactions by BIP-11?

Have a look here: https://webbtc.com/stats and here: https://webbtc.com/scripts/multisig

Or may be you are interested in BIP-16 mostly used for multisig?

Take this link: http://p2sh.info

Answer (score 2):

You can find stats on P2SH here:

http://p2sh.info/dashboard/db/p2sh-statistics

"Pay to script hash

Pay to script hash (P2SH) transactions were standardised in BIP 16. They allow transactions to be sent to a script hash (address starting with 3) instead of a public key hash (addresses starting with 1). To spend bitcoins sent via P2SH, the recipient must provide a script matching the script hash and data which makes the script evaluate to true.

Using P2SH, you can send bitcoins to an address that is secured in various unusual ways without knowing anything about the details of how the security is set up. You just send bitcoins to the ~34-character P2SH address. The recipient might need the signatures of several people to spend these bitcoins, or a password might be required, or the requirements could be completely unique."

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash

Comment: You may want to draw more attention to your link at the top.  Since your answer is mostly just a quote from the wiki, it's hard to see that you actually answered the question.  Just add something like, "you can find stats on P2SH here:", or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Real time updated statistics on all bitcoin outputs

https://bitaps.com/statistic/outputs

[image]